# How to silence Eclipse's "Android SDK Missing" warnings

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, suppress-warnings

About a year ago, I first installed Eclipse for Android app development, but shortly later decided not to pursue this. Now I am using Eclipse for Java and C++ programming, but Eclipse reminds me with two to four warning boxes (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2ZyE.jpg) that I am missing the Android SDK every time I launch it. I have no desire to install (and update) the Android SDK because I am not doing Android development. How may I silence these warnings? Is there an option in the massive preferences to make Eclipse forget about Android? I have tried:

• Deleting files located in `~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.eclipse`, `~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist`, and the metadata files of my projects

• Searching StackOverflow and Google for people with the same problem (there aren't any or everyone else understands something I don't)

• Downloading the Android SDK (worked but then wanted to be updated a few weeks later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to uninstall all software moduls related to Android in Eclipse?

Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details

Comment: I tried this, and it said I uninstalled the modules; however, they remained in the list when I went back, without letting me edit their entries. I then tried reverting to a previous "module configuration" (can't remember the exact name) in that same dialog. This got rid of the modules successfully, but I was still getting the dialog boxes. Eventually I just deleted all Eclipse files on my computer and reinstalled from scratch. This worked (although I am very unsatisfied with Eclipse).